# SourceSafe Sharing a Folder?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

Imagine sharing a Visual Studio project and its accompanying files between two SourceSafe projects A and B.

If you add a new project item to project A, the project is updated and the new item is added to A's project. However, while B's project file is updated (because it is shared with A), it now has a missing item--because the new item added to A isn't shared.

It seems to me that this can be solved by sharing an entire folder in SourceSafe. But can you even do this?

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that branching would solve your problem. 
If you have project A and project B, and branch those out to work on them then adding the items like you suggested would stay in the branch.
However once you merged back into the main trunk you would have the item you added in your branch available to both A and B

Hope I explained that ok.
Here is a link that is very helpful and explains branching well.

http://geekswithblogs.net/VROD/archive/2006/11/22/97817.aspx

Comment: Yes, I could branch. But I'd like to not branch. I want to share the projects and items between two (or more) sourcesafe projects.

Comment: You could try:  
Setting the working space for all the folders & Setting permissions through VSS Admin
That might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can share a folder via SourceSafe client. But the newly added items in a project won't appear in the other project. Only the existing items will be updated automatically.

Comment: Then I think that means the folder isn't actually being shared---only the original items that were there at the time the sharing was done.